# Number of photons in the Compton effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons

In the Compton effect,a photon collides with an electron and thus the electron drifts away acquiring the energy $k=hf-hf'$. But isn't this possible for a single photon only? It isn't possible for the electron to interact with more than one photon staying in the same place. In that case why is it said that light interacts with electron? Can light consist of one photon only? In that case what will the light look like since photons are only packets of energy?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the Compton effect is only interesting for high-energy, low-density photon-electron systems, where the most probable number of scattering interactions is zero. In that case, the second-most probable number of scattering interactions is one.

Imagine a nucleus which emits gamma rays from a particular excited state, so that all of the gamma rays have almost exactly the same energy. If you were to make a histogram with “photon energy” on one axis and “number of photons” on the other, an ideal experiment would have all of your monoenergetic photons filling a spike at the energy of the transition. But in a real experiment, that spike is accompanied by a “shoulder” of lower-energy photons which have lost energy by Compton scattering between the emitter and the detector.

As for what this would look like: you can’t see gamma rays. If you could observe Compton scattering with visible light (which I think you can’t, but the reason warrants a separate question), the energy exchange between the photons and the electrons would mean that a blue light source would be reddened as the thickness of material between the source and the emitter increased. Perceptually it is the same basic idea as the reddening of sunlight through the atmosphere, so that the white sun looks red at dusk. However, Rayleigh scattering (which makes the sky blue and the sunset red) is an *elastic* process: the photons don’t lose energy, but instead the higher-energy blue photons are preferentially scattered. In a hypothetical sky colored by Compton scattering, the scattered light would have less energy than the unscattered light, making the sky red instead of blue.

Comment: "... observe Compton scattering with visible light (which I think you can’t, but the reason warrants a separate question), ..." - Can there be a sole exchange of direction according to Newton's third law? In a perfect elastic process between two equal masses there should be only exchange of direction ("radial" forces). Are there any theories about he electron amounting to some organized heap of photon quants? The less the energy of the photon the more there is exchange of direction solely?

Comment: @PeterBernhard It is a question of whether one analyzes the interaction in the lab frame or the center-of-momentum frame (which depends on the momentum transferred in the interaction). Scattering events with very small momentum transfer can be described using the elastic approximation of [Thomson scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_scattering); if you boost a Thomson-scattering event into a reference frame where the initial electron is at rest but the initial photon has high energy, it corresponds to a Compton-scattering event with very small forward angle.

Comment: I will follow your helpful link.  Ref. to "very small forward angle", what I was suggesting implies that a small forw. angle amounts to a  "large exchange" of direction, thus, I do not feel corrected on my statement: the lesser the energy the "purer" the exchange of direction. I will rethink "symmetries" considering reflection angles, only hoping you understand. Please correct if Compton angles are NOT a matter of QM (as mass is zero tangens function in Newtonian impulse laws do not apply(?) -  sure makes up some other question). Again, thank you for your advice.

Comment: A large “exchange of direction” is backscattering, not forward scattering. Compton’s Nobel was awarded in part because Compton scattering requires particle-like interactions with the electromagnetic field.

Comment: yeah, my own intricacy is to define "pure" exchange different from "small", as with Thomson scattering it's the mirror in the bathroom, the scattering is "pure symmetry". There is - almost - no transfer of energy that would not "amount to direction". What causes "large" backscattering? It is the changing of the frequency indicating an exchange of energy. That's what I was trying to say mentioning "symmetry": Snell's law of the Newtonian mirror is "pure" symmetry. Just now, it occurs to me that a large backward angle - I'd say - compensates loss of energy.  I will think it over. Thank you!

Comment: You may be better off with a follow-up question. But if the scattering angle is nonzero, you can *always* rotate/boost into a center-of-momentum reference frame where the photon and electron both backscatter, reversing their initial momenta. Think of low-photon-energy Thomson scattering as thrown pebbles bouncing off of a brick wall, and high-energy Compton scattering as a wrecking ball which moves the wall instead. If the wrecking ball has a glancing collision, the wall may survive. As for "what causes": the cross section versus angle is a standard (if advanced) homework problem.

Comment: There is *always* momentum exchange in a collision. In the limit where the masses of the colliding objects are very different, such as a pebble striking a brick wall (especially if the brick wall is securely attached to a large rock, such as a bedrock), the more massive object can change its momentum with a *negligible* change in velocity. When you bounce a ball off a basketball court, the ball comes back up because the court has, very slightly, moved down.